# Swift Cannot construct string with argument type Int64

Tags: swift, string, casting, sprite-kit, int64

I am making a game that involves a Game Center leaderboard. I want to make a custom leaderboard UI rather than using the default interface.

I am trying to convert the values stored in a Game Center leaderboard into a string so that I may display them using an SKLabelNode. However, I get an error saying that:

> Cannot invoke initializer for type 'String' with an argument list of type '(Int64?)'

I am accessing the Game Center scores using

```
leaderboard.scores[i].value
```

When I use the `String(describing: )` method, my label node reads "optional(10)", with whatever the score is being inside the parenthesis. I am wondering how to cleanly convey the data store in Game Center into a number in string format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try optional binding:

```
if let unwrapped = leaderboard.scores[i].value {
    let string = String(unwrapped)
    print(string)
}
```

Or use the guard statement if you want to use the unwrapped value in the rest of the scope:

```
guard let unwrapped = leaderboard.scores[i].value else {
    fatalError("Couldn't unwrap the score value")
}
let string = String(unwrapped)
```